# This error won't go away error: expected flags but got (raw string) 0x0

Tags: java, android

This error popped up while building

> ERROR:C:\gradels\new one\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1508: AAPT: error: expected flags but got (raw string) 0x0.

And When I clicked on the file and tried editing it but it keeps saying "Files under build folder are generated and should not be edited"  This error weren't there when I was using android sdk 31 but a lot of other errors were popping up while using 31 so I downgraded to 30 and now a bunch of errors all in the same file "values.xml" is popping and when I clicks on the error it directs me to the values.xml file and won't let me edit it saying the error listed in the title

`ERROR:C:\gradels\new one\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1508: AAPT: error: expected flags but got (raw string) 0x0`.

Here's my android manifest file and build.gradle

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:versionCode="30100715" android:versionName="3.1.0.715" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.cmplay.tiles2"
 platformBuildVersionCode="26" platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
     <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000"/>
     <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.umonistudio.tile.permission.AIDL_SERVICE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
     <meta-data android:name="CMPLAY_SYNC_IPC" android:value="com.cmplay.kinfoc.sync"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
     <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.GameApp" android:allowBackup="true"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:supportsRtl="true"
 android:fullBackupContent="@xml/vungle_backup_rule">
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/google_app_id"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.LoveShareActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.ChristmasShareActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:exported="false"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.SongMixShareActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
 android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleFlexViewActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
 android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:name="com.sina.weibo.sdk.component.WeiboSdkBrowser"
 android:exported="false"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
 android:exported="false"
 android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2.wxapi.WXEntryActivity"
 android:exported="true"/>
         <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true"
 android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1635899819990716"/>
         <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled"
 android:value="false"/>
         <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled"
 android:value="false"/>
         <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id_gp"/>
         <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>
         <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>
         <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="UdAAPq-zrVhcaaKovlmPEn8qXmrUnzGFbRP_FOz5uehTE0G7l0X-nfpJPepBc3QCVrClEAr7qWa2XsAHshGdM4"/>
         <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.verbose_logging" android:value="false"/>
         <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.privacy.ConsentDialogActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.RewardedMraidActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.webview.ui.WebViewActivity"
 android:exported="true" android:process=":web"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="orientation"/>
         <activity android:theme="@style/dialog" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.TipsGetGiftSuccedDialog"
 android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.OpenScreenActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
         <provider android:name="com.cmplay.webview.ipc.WebIpcProvider" android:exported="false" android:process=":web"
 android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.ipc.web"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
 android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.CMCampaignTrackingReceiver"
 android:exported="true" android:process=":service">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.WebBroadcast"
 android:exported="true" android:process=":web">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.webbroadcast"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.GameBroadcast"
 android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.gamebroadcast"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.notification.EnergyReceiver"
 android:exported="true" android:process=":service">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.cmplay.notification.EnergyReceiver"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <meta-data android:name="UMENG_APPKEY" android:value="55a86f6667e58e298100016b"/>
         <meta-data android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL" android:value="gp"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
 android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
 android:exported="true" android:process=":service">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                 <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <service android:name="com.cmplay.gcmPush.MyGcmListenerService"
 android:exported="false" android:process=":service">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </service>
         <service android:name="com.cmplay.gcmPush.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
 android:exported="false" android:process=":service">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </service>
         <service android:name="com.cmplay.gcmPush.RegistrationIntentService"
 android:exported="false" android:process=":service"/>
         <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:name="io.display.sdk.DioActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="io.display.sdk.DioTranslucentActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
             tools:ignore="MissingClass" />
         <activity android:name="io.display.sdk.device.PermissionsHandler"/>
         <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.33"/>
         <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="cocos2dcpp"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.AppActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="layoutDirection|screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|locale">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                 <data android:scheme="https" android:host="fb.me"/>
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                 <data android:scheme="piano2"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.ShareActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="layoutDirection|screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|locale"/>
         <activity android:theme="@style/dialog" android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.GameProblemActivity"
 android:process=":service" android:taskAffinity="com.gameproblem"
 android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
         <activity android:theme="@style/dialog2" android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.exitpopup.GameExitPopupActivity"
 android:process=":service" android:taskAffinity="com.gameexit"
 android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="com.cmplay.util.crop.CropImageActivity"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="layoutDirection|orientation|locale"/>
         <service android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.ReportService" android:process=":service"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.util.ConnectionChangedReceiver"
 android:exported="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.notification.NotificationDeleteReceiver"
 android:enabled="true" android:process=":service"/>
         <provider android:name="com.cmplay.ipc.IpcProvider" android:exported="false" android:process=":service"
 android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.ipc_provider"/>
         <provider android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.NullProvider" android:exported="false"
 android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.null_provider"/>
         <service android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.export.DumpReportService"
 android:exported="true" android:process=":crashReport"/>
         <meta-data android:name="SET_PROMOTION_LOG" android:value="false"/>
         <service android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.InnerPushService"
 android:process=":service"/>
         <provider android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.ipc.IpcProvider" android:exported="false" android:process=":service"
 android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.innerpush_provider"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.OpenScreenVideoActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.InsertScreenActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.video.IncentiveVideoPlayActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.video.VideoAdDetailActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.GameBroadcast"
 android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.gamebroadcast"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.notify.NotifyReceiver">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.notify"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <provider android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
 android:exported="false"
 android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.FacebookInitProvider"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver"
 android:exported="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <activity android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"/>
         <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity"/>
         <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.wxapi.WXEntryActivity"
 android:exported="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.baidu.wxapi.WXEntryActivity"
 android:exported="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.m4399.wxapi.WXEntryActivity"
 android:exported="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.uc.wxapi.WXEntryActivity"
 android:exported="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.tencent.tmgp.tiles2.wxapi.WXEntryActivity"
 android:exported="true"/>
         <meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="26.1.0"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
 android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
         <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
 android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
         <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsJobService"
 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
 android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
 android:exported="false"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
 android:exported="false" android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
         <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
 android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION"
 android:exported="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
 android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity"
 android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity"
 android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
 android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
         <service android:name="com.cmplay.crashreport.CrashReportService"
 android:process=":crashReport"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.crashreport.WifiStateReceiver"
 android:process=":crashReport">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <activity android:name="com.facebook.notifications.internal.activity.CardActivity"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.videoad.VideoActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="user"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.interstitialAd.InterstitialActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.interactivead.InteractiveActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.AdtWebActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.extra.HelpActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <activity android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleWebViewActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
 android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
         <receiver android:name="com.vungle.warren.NetworkStateReceiver"
 android:enabled="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
     </application> </manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 30
 
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId 'com.cmplay.tiles2'
         minSdkVersion 21
         targetSdkVersion 30
         versionCode 30100715
         versionName "3.1.0.715"

         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
 
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 
     compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
     lint {
         abortOnError false
     }
 
 }
 
 dependencies {
     def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
     implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
     // some dependencies }
```

Comment: Do you actually have all those `>` signs in your file?  That seems like a problem, if so - otherwise you should remove them from the question.

Comment: @RyanM No I don't know how those signs appeared in this but they are not there in the file

Comment: You should [edit] the question to remove them.

Comment: @RyanM Yeah done but any solution to the errors?

Comment: What's line 1508 of `C:\gradels\new one\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml`?

Comment: @RyanM <item name="android:textStyle">0x0</item> keep in mind this file can not be  edited

Comment: Yeah, but everything in it comes from somewhere...is there an `<item name="android:textStyle">` somewhere with a value of `0` or `0x0` or something like that?

Comment: @RyanM Yeah yeah their is! in values/styles.xml <item name="android:textStyle">0x0</item> and the "0x0" is flagged in red by android studio I don't know why

Comment: @RyanM I added "normal" instead of "0x0" and it fixed the issue and then another issue popped up "Illegal char <:> at index 43: com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml"